Get images back from patches
I use a function to creates patches of shape (i,j,c,h,w) from an image (c,h,w) with overlap like so:
def create_patches(image, patch_size=224, overlap=0):
    _, height, width = image.shape
    step = patch_size - overlap
    padding_width = (step - (width - overlap) % step) % step
    padding_height = (step - (height - overlap) % step) % step
    image = F.pad(image, (0, 0, padding_width, padding_height))
    return (
        image
        .unfold(0, 3, 3)
        .unfold(1, patch_size, step)
        .unfold(2, patch_size, step)
    )

org_image = read_image("image.png")
print(org_image.shape) #torch.Size([3, 669, 1046])
patches = create_patches(org_image, patch_size=224, overlap=24)
print(patches.shape) #torch.Size([4, 6, 3, 224, 224])

I wonder how I could reverse the process in order to get the image back from the patches.
Note that I am using a super resolution model so the patches shape after eval will be (i,j,c,h*scale_factor, w*scale_factor) for instance torch.Size([4, 6, 3, 896, 896]) for a scale_factor of 4.
